# Footer doesn't update when item deleted in UITableView

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I have my DataSource class with an override for the TitleForFooter, which I use to provide a total value of the items in my TableView.

When an item is deleted, in the CommitEditingStyle method, I have the delete with animation

SummaryTable.DeleteRows(new [] { _indexPath }, UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade);

However, the footer isn't updated to reflect the new total. What's the best way to do this? I couldn't find a Footer or Footertitle method on the table that I could manually update.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you've got some code in the `TitleForFooter` which performs a count?
In which case Reloading the data should refresh the footer count for you:

```
InvokeOnMainThread(delegate{
  SummaryTable.ReloadData();
});
```